# Why does my code provide an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to understand why my code creates an infinite loop :

```
const [row, setRow] = useState(1);
<textarea>
rows={row}
        value={value}
        placeholder="Votre message"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onClick={setRow((current) => current + 2)}
        onBlur={setRow((current) => current - 2)}
      ></textarea>
```

Could someone tells me why `onClick` and `onBlur` create infinite loops ?

Answer (score 0):

in onClick and onBlur you need to pass function not calling function.
so change this :

```
const [row, setRow] = useState(1);
<textarea>
        rows={row}
        value={value}
        placeholder="Votre message"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onClick={setRow((current) => current + 2)}
        onBlur={setRow((current) => current - 2)}
      ></textarea>
```

to this:

```
const [row, setRow] = useState(1);
   <textarea>
        rows={row}
        value={value}
        placeholder="Votre message"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onClick={ ()=> setRow((current) => current + 2)}
        onBlur={ ()=> setRow((current) => current - 2)}
      ></textarea>
```

Comment: it's my pleasure :)